# Rank generation of 500000 or more records in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, database-design, analytics

I am suffering from a problem from the last 5 days and not yet decided how to do it in the right manner.

I have currently 100000 record in my table I need to generate the rank of these record on the basis of a field suppose it is the user's scores.

Currently, I am generating rank manually and it is taking a lot of time in the future their record may reach up to 1000000 or more.

Currently, I am using MySQL v5.7 and there is no function for the rank generation I am also planning to change the database.

So can any please suggest me a good way to complete this task.

I am working on it from few last days and still not found any good solution

If anyone can suggest a good solution I will be really very grateful.

I am ready to do it on another database just the point is it should not take too much time

Manually ranking means first I read all the records and then iterate via loop then check the user's score and update their rank

Comment: Manually? You mean like with a pen and paper?

Comment: Hmm.. How are you generating the ranks? From what I see, you can write SQL query to get the top ranks ( scores ) out of your records. That won't be that difficult to do.

Comment: Manually ranking means first I read all the records and then iterate via loop then check the user's score and update their rank

Comment: How does the user score distibution work? e.g. is it always +20 or -20 and are your ranks depended on these scores or is it the highest is rank 1?

Comment: yes highest is rank 1 and same scores will get the same rank

Comment: Ranking 100K rows will be slow; ranking 1M will be sloooooow.  Rethink the requirement for dynamic ranking.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to ask for a clarification in answer page (not having enough reputation to comment)..

first of all you cannot query all 100000 records and loop it at a time, you might get memory exhaust error.

if you are gonna use limit and offset to get batches of records but i know this is a time consuming process.

checkout

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/

```
INSERT INTO t(val)
VALUES(1),(2),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5);

SELECT
val,
RANK() OVER (
ORDER BY val
) my_rank
FROM
t;
```

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7 which doesn't support window functions

Comment: Upgrade to MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2 for windowing functions.